# How to generate 11 char hash key for Sms Retriever with Google App signing

Tags: android, command-line, google-play, keytool

I had generated the 11 char hash using the `AppSignatureHelper` class. But after uploading the apk to play store, they hash doesn't work anymore. And I found out that Play replaces the key with another one which is why the hash gets changed as well. Now I'm having trouble getting the 11 char hash key.

I don't know how to use the commands given by Google. I found this command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50600769/4961874)

`` keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11 ``

Since, Play App signing is enabled for my app, I'll have to use this command,

`` keytool -exportcert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11 ``

I've replaced `keytool` with its path from the JDK's bin folder but then it was saying `xxd` was not recognized so I downloaded it from a website now it's saying `tr` is not recognized, I guess it'll say that for `cut` as well.

Please pardon me if it seems too noob of me asking it, but how can I resolve this?

**UPDATE:** I've tried the second command from above on a linux machine, the command worked and gave me 11 character hash but still the SMS Retriever is not working.

**SOLUTION:** With the help of Nick Fortescue's answer, I downloaded the DER formatted file. Then converted it to a .jks file using the following command,

`keytool -importcert -alias myalias -file deployment_cert.der -keystore certificate.jks -storepass mypassword`

Then performed the first command from above on certificate.jks and it worked!

Comment: How to generate hash into windows machine, because I am also facing same issue. xxd, tr, ... not recognized.

Comment: @AnkitKumarSingh I used Linux. I don't know how to do it on Windows.

Comment: @AnkitKumarSingh You can use bash terminal to execute that command on Windows.

Comment: can someone please explain do I need to replace MyProductionKeys.keystore with my keystore or it's a part of command

Comment: @HemendraKhatik replace it with your own keystore

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here is the complete step by step guide .

1. Go to play console -> open app -> Release management -> App Signing -> Download Certificate . Like in below screen shot

[image]

This will give you **`deployment_cert.der`** file

2. Convert the **`deployment_cert.der`** file to a **`.jks`** file

use below command

```
keytool -importcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -file deployment_cert.der -keystore certificate.jks -storepass YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Replace YOUR_ALIAS,YOUR_PASSWORD with yours which used in keystore . In place of **`deployment_cert.der`** use complete path if required

After entering this command it will ask

> Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes

type yes and click enter . It will show message

> Certificate was added to keystore

This will generate a new file **`certificate.jks`**

3. Now in terminal enter command

   `` keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11 ``

Replace YOUR_ALIAS,YOUR_PACKAGE with yours which used in keystore,project . In place of **`certificate.jks`** use complete path if required

it will ask for password

> Enter keystore password:  mypassword

enter your password and you will get the hash .

### EDIT For MacOS users:

If you're using MacOS you can install sha256sum by installing coreutils like this:

`brew install coreutils`

Or you can use `shasum -a 256` instead of `sha256sum` like this:

`` keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE `cat` | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11 ``

Credits to [Abhinav Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54216303/6478047) and Op of this question [Farhan Farooqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51365778/6478047) and above answer from [Nick Fortescue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375789/6478047)

Comment: The perfect solution, Works!! Thanks. I had to read a bunch of app's signing process to get my head around it.

Comment: Hi I'm getting following error, keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Comment: for me hashstring not generating after entering the password in mac

Comment: I followed all the steps and got the hash key. I added the hash key to my SMS. But still, it is not working on play store apk.

Comment: May be you entered wrong password in the last step , use your jks/keystore password

Comment: for mac if <echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE `cat` > doesn't work, replace it with <xargs echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE>

Comment: How do I get the hash key if my app is still in development and I did not signin with Google?

Comment: @Akshaykumar see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849023/android-sms-retriever-api-computing-apps-hash-string-problem

Comment: It does not ask `password` for me, and shows error: <some code> `tr: write error`

Comment: make sure your the command, ALIAS, Application id are correct .

Comment: @ManoharReddy it showed `hashCode` but release version still is not getting SMS

Comment: If it didn't ask for password then it will give wrong value . Only with correct password you will get right hashcode

Comment: You won't need to download certficate from Play Console if you have already jks or extensionless keystore file. Use it to get the hash key.

Comment: Help! Stuck after entering password.

Comment: I have the same problem as @KuvonchbekYakubov.

Comment: On windows, you need to gitbash to specific directory and then run above command to get the hash string. CMD is giving error saying xxd is not recognized as an internal command.

Answer (score 15):

As default bash commands were not working for me and I needed to generate hashes for both local keystore and Google Play certificate, I wrote my own Ruby script for that: https://github.com/michalbrz/sms-retriever-hash-generator/blob/master/google_play_sign.rb

Then generating hash with Google Play signing is just:

```
ruby google_play_sign.rb --package com.your.app --google-play-key deployment_key.der
```

where `deployment_key.der` is certificate downloaded from Google Play as in [Nick's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51375789/2707179).

Under the hood it transforms Google Play cert into keystore and basically does what other suggested bash commands do, but wraps it in something easier to use.

Comment: I'm getting this doing your command, some suggestion why I can't get the hash: ruby google_play_sign.rb --package com.xxxx.xxxx --google-play-key deployment_key.der
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from google_play_sign.rb:86:in `<main>'
        1: from google_play_sign.rb:59:in `der_to_keystore'
google_play_sign.rb:59:in ``': No such file or directory - keytool -importcert       -alias myalias       -file deployment_key.der       -keystore gp_imported_keystore_temp.jks       -storepass mypassword -noprompt (Errno::ENOENT)

Comment: @S.P. Simple explanation would be that your `deployment_key.der` doesn't exists. Are you sure you are putting correct path there? If you're sure, you can check if command `keytool -importcert -alias myalias -file DER_FILE_PATH -keystore gp_imported_keystore_temp.jks -storepass pwd -noprompt` would work for you - of course you should substitute DER_FILE_PATH with real path.

Answer (score 9):

In [the help documents for Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423) it has a section "New Apps". Step 4 in this section is:

> Step 4: Register your app signing key with API providers
>   If your app uses any API, you will usually need to register the certificate of the key Google signs your app with for authentication purposes. This is usually done through the fingerprint of the certificate.
>
> To find the certificate of the key Google uses to re-sign your APK for delivery:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
>
>    2. Select an app.
>    3. On the left menu, click Release management > App signing.
>    4. From this page, you can copy the most common fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-256) of your app signing certificate. If the API provider requires a different type of fingerprint, you can also download the original certificate in DER format and run it through the transformation tools that the API provider requires.

Download the original certificate in DER format and then use your command on that certificate.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've found the DER formatted file, Now I just have to replace `MyProductionKeys.keystore` with the DER file's path in the command?

Comment: I had used the SHA-256 before and tried to get the 11 char Hash, but that doesn't work either, SMS Retriever can't detect it

Comment: I got below error : keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match

Comment: `keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11` this command needs alias which is not provided with Play provided DER file.

Comment: Use alias you used in main keystore file

Answer (score 6):

These steps worked for me on Mac:

0. Upload a build (need not be functional) and release to at least internal testing track.
1. Download app signing certificate from google play console (setup (left sidebar navigation) > App Integrity > App Signing):
   [image]
2. Go to downloads folder and run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

```
➜ keytool -importcert -alias my-upload-key-alias -file deployment_cert.der -keystore certificate.jks -storepass notARealPassword

...

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore
```

```
➜ keytool -exportcert -alias my-upload-key-alias -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | xargs echo -n com.myapp | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
Enter keystore password: notARealPassword
6bAhwera2r5
```

`6bAhwera2r5` is your 11 char hash key which you can use for SMS Retriever feature.

3. Append the hash to the end of sms that want to be autodetected and content to be passed to you app by android. Example template:

```
<#> Dear customer, {#var#} is your one time password for AppName account verification. 6bAhwera2r5
```

this template is compliant with Indian DLT rules.

Answer (score 3):

I know I replied very late. But I got the solution for this.

First follow the steps given by Manoher Reddy as above.

If this not work, try following alternate solution, it worked for me in various apps:

provide the play store generated hash to backend. For generating hash key on playstore, i have used AppSignatureHelper class and make Toast for the generated hash key and upload this build on play store. After successfully rollout, i have download the build. Now Toast will show with the playstore generated hash key, provide this key to backend. It is working fine for me.

Comment: yes, unfortunalty my log was enabled and it was printed new key(with appSignatureHelper calss) with play store apk and its woking fine

Answer (score 1):

Go to play console -> open app ->App integrity -> App signing

EDIT For MacOS users:
If you're using MacOS you can install sha256sum by installing coreutils like this:

brew install coreutils

Or you can use shasum -a 256 instead of sha256sum like this:

keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore certificate.jks | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE `cat` | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias *Alias -keystore *keystorePath | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

replace *Alias with your alias and *keystorePath with your kestore location. Also put right path of openssl.exe if its installed to another directory

Answer (score -1):

I found all those commands and the process itself a little bit messy (I also have projects with 4 environment with 4 different packages), so what I did is to include the hash on the payload from the client when the client request a OTP, then the server save it (trust on first use) for manual review on the content management system.
Didn't find any security aspect using this method