# Android - SMS Retriever API - Computing app's hash string problem

Tags: android

I am really new in Android and I am trying to implement the SMS Retriever API for using OTP in my app.

I am following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string

Unfortunately I'm stuck in the part of "**Computing your app's hash string**"

I am quoting here the guide sections, and below each one- my question:

1. Get your app's public key certificate as a lower-case hex string. For example, to get the hex string from your keystore, type the following command

   ```
   keytool -alias MyAndroidKey -exportcert -keystore MyProduction.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]"
   ```

**Where can I find my "public key certificate", and where am I supposed to run this command?**

2. Compute the SHA-256 sum of the combined string.

**What is SHA-256 and what does it mean to compute it?**

3. Base64-encode the binary value of the SHA-256 sum. You might need to decode the SHA-256 sum from its output format first.

**Can't understand, what am I supposed to do here?**

Comment: use the Signing keystore of your app to get the public key certificate

Comment: have you generated your keystore file and signed apk or you want to do it for debug apk?

Answer (score 45):

Google has created [a script](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/bin/sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh) to wrap the necessary CLI commands to generate the app hash.

Usage is:

```
./sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh --package "com.your.packagename" --keystore /path/to/your.keystore
```

Example output:

```
$ ./sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh --package "com.your.packagename" --keystore debug.keystore

package name: com.your.packagename
keystore file: debug.keystore

File debug.keystore is found.

Enter keystore password:  


certificate in hex: 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

SHA-256 output in hex: 20e861ecc8550c1e608efc3006f82278025d5e3d7169b40c72b8c3dd0aa9cfd9

First 8 bytes encoded by base64: IOhh7MhVDB5

SMS Retriever hash code:  IOhh7MhVDB5
```

Save [the raw script file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/master/sms-verification/bin/sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh) locally then run `chmod u+x sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh` to make it executable.

In case the link to the script disappears, here's the script contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

# ------------------------------------------------------------------
# [Author] Title
#          Description
# ------------------------------------------------------------------

VERSION=0.1.0
SUBJECT=sms-retriever-hash-generator
USAGE="Usage: sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh --package package_name --keystore keystore_file"

# --- Options processing -------------------------------------------
if [ $# == 0 ] ; then
    echo $USAGE
    exit 1;
fi

# USE: apkblacklister.sh --source source.apk --target target.apk more files to scan

if [[ "$1" != "--package" ]]; then
  echo "Error: expected --package as first parameter"
  exit 1
fi
pkg="$2"
shift 2

if [[ "$1" != "--keystore" ]]; then
  echo "Error: expected --keystore as third parameter"
  exit 1
fi
keystore="$2"
shift 2



echo
echo "package name: $pkg"
echo "keystore file: $keystore"
echo 

if [ -e "$keystore" ]
then
  echo "File $keystore is found."
  echo
else
  echo "File $keystore is not found."
  echo
  exit 0;
fi

# Retrieve certificate from keystore file. Decoded with Base64 and converted to hex
cert=$(keytool -list -rfc -keystore $keystore | sed  -e '1,/BEGIN/d' | sed -e '/END/,$d' | tr -d ' \n' | base64 --decode | xxd -p | tr -d ' \n')

echo
echo "certificate in hex: $cert"


# concatenate input
input="$pkg $cert"

# 256 bits = 32 bytes = 64 hex chars
output=$(printf "$input" | shasum -a 256 | cut -c1-64)
echo
echo "SHA-256 output in hex: $output"

# take the beginning 72 bits (= 9 bytes = 18 hex chars)
output=$(printf $output | cut -c1-18)

# encode sha256sum output by base64 (11 chars)
base64output=$(printf $output | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11)
echo
echo "First 8 bytes encoded by base64: $base64output"
echo
echo "SMS Retriever hash code:  $base64output"
echo
```

Comment: Replace `#!/bin/sh` -> `#!/bin/bash`, because it's bash not Bourne Shell (`[[` not valid in sh). Replace `tr -d ' \n'` -> `tr -d '[:space:]'`

Comment: command working great. But onReceive callback is not called (((

Comment: On mac, it is saying Sorry!

Answer (score 26):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


/*
  This is a helper class to generate your message hash to be included in your SMS message.

  Without the correct hash, your app won't recieve the message callback. This only needs to be
  generated once per app and stored. Then you can remove this helper class from your code.
*/

public class AppSignatureHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static final String TAG = AppSignatureHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
    public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
    public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

    public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getAppSignatures();
    }

    /**
     * Get all the app signatures for the current package
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
        ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            // Get all package signatures for the current package
            String packageName = getPackageName();
            PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
            Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

            // For each signature create a compatible hash
            for (Signature signature : signatures) {
                String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
                if (hash != null) {
                    appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
                }

                Log.v(TAG, "Hash " + hash);

            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
        }
        return appCodes;
    }

    private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
        String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }
            byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

            // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
            hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
            // encode into Base64
            String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
            base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

            Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
            return base64Hash;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add the above class in your project and then call it from your **LoginActivity** like below:

```
AppSignatureHelper appSignatureHelper = new AppSignatureHelper(LoginActivity.this);
```

This way you will get 11 digit hash and you'll be able to get it as:

```
Log.v(TAG, appSignatureHelper.getAppSignatures().get(0));
```

Comment: This worked for me Thanks just add `appSignatureHelper.getAppSignatures();` to call the method inside  `AppSignatureHelper`

Comment: Added @LuisAguilar

Comment: @FaisalShaikh it will work for release version also. I used this code for play store deployment only.

Comment: Here's a Gist of the two nearly identical Android hash-extractors converted to kotlin and with SDK28 variant for signatures: https://gist.github.com/arberg/ac70e2ecc4f3c7249c52b639309d0900

Answer (score 17):

```
First way:
```

---

if you want to make hash string sms for your app that is signed on play store then download the app signing certificate from play store. go to release management->app signing, the folder will be called deployment_cer.der :

then change this .der file to jks file using this code

```
keytool -importcert -alias examplealias -file deployment_cert.der -keystore certificate.jks -storepass examplepass
```

trust the certificate and you will have the certificate to use instead of keystore

now you have the certificate.jks from live you use this code to generate the 11 hash string:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias anything -keystore '/home/adminuser/Documents/user/certificate.jks' | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.firstapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

put the password and then the hash string will show for the uploaded live version apk

these codes are if you are working on linux. now if you want to work on windows you can replace the xxd and the tr from the files that you can [download here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bsmh0ubg6pa51sr/xxd_tr.rar/file)

**NOTE**: if you want to test the app before uploading to store then change the keystore with your keystore that you have not the converted .jks file

### Second way:

you can make a class in your app to generate the code

```
public class SmsVerification extends ContextWrapper {
public static final String TAG = SmsVerify.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

public SmsVerification (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * Get all the app signatures for the current package
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Get all package signatures for the current package
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
    }
    return appCodes;
}

private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and call the function inside the class:

```
ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();
SmsVerify hash = new SmsVerify(activity);
appCodes= hash.getAppSignatures();
String yourhash = appCodes.get(0);
```

Comment: first way will be failed on windows 10 with multiple warning of missing dll(s). and this message on command line: `'sha256sum' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Thank you! It's working for me. The Second way. I couldn't get the xxd and tr in windows in First way

Comment: Here's a Gist of the two nearly identical Android hash-extractors converted to kotlin and with SDK28 variant for signatures: https://gist.github.com/arberg/ac70e2ecc4f3c7249c52b639309d0900

Comment: Second way depends on the Windows machine you build your apk.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following script which is able to generate the hashcode either from a `*.keystore` file or the `*.der` file (which you can download from the Play Console):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

error() { printf "%s\n" "$1" >&2; exit 1; }

command -v keytool &> /dev/null || error "Command 'keytool' not found"
(( $# >= 2 )) || error "Usage: $(basename "$0") <file.der | file.keystore alias> appId"

file=$1

[[ -r $file ]] || error "'$file' doesn't exist or isn't readable"
if [[ $file = *.keystore ]]; then
  keystore=$file
  alias=$2
  [[ $3 ]] || error "Missing application id argument"
  app_id=$3
elif [[ $file = *.der ]]; then
  trap 'code=$?; rm -rf -- "$tmp_folder"; exit "$code"' EXIT SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGTERM
  tmp_folder=$(mktemp -d)
  keystore=$tmp_folder/tmp.keystore
  alias=temp
  app_id=$2
  keytool -importcert -file "$file" -keystore "$keystore" -alias "$alias"
else
  error "'$file' needs to be of type *.der or *.keystore"
fi

keytool -exportcert -keystore "$keystore" -alias "$alias" | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | printf '%s %s' "$app_id" "$(cat)" | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

Usage:

```
./script deployment_cert.der com.example.retriever
./script upload.keystore upload com.example.retriever
```

Answer (score 3):

With **terminal** command (works with `macOS terminal` or for Windows `Right click on folder and click Git Bash Here`):

1. Download **deployment_cert.der** from google play console.
2. Run command in terminal: `keytool -importcert -file deployment_cert.der -keystore temp.keystore -alias 'your_alias'`
3. Run command: `(echo your.package && echo ' ' && keytool -exportcert -alias your_alias -keystore temp.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]") | tr -d '\n' | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11`
4. Full [commands](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string).

With **python** script(works on macOS):

1. Download **deployment_cert.der** from google play console.
2. Run command in terminal: `keytool -importcert -file deployment_cert.der -keystore temp.keystore -alias 'your_alias'`
3. Download [smshash.py](https://github.com/funambol/android-sms-hash-generator)
4. Run command in terminal: `python3 smshash.py temp.keystore 'your_alias' 'your_keystore_password' 'your.package'`

If the link to [smshash.py](https://github.com/funambol/android-sms-hash-generator) becomes unavailable, create python file.

```
import platform
import os
import sys
import argparse
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import base64
from shutil import which
try:
    import hashlib
except ImportError:
    sys.exit("please install 'hashlib' module: pip install hashlib")

#the parser
cmd_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Computing app's hash string for Android SMS handling")
cmd_parser.add_argument('keystore', type=str, help='Keystore file')
cmd_parser.add_argument('alias', type=str, help='Keystore alias')
cmd_parser.add_argument('keypass', type=str, help='Key password')
cmd_parser.add_argument('appid', type=str, help='Package name of the Android app')
args = cmd_parser.parse_args()

__encoding_name__ = "iso-8859-1" # Latin 1

def isWindows():
    return platform.system() == "Windows"

def cmdExist(program):
    return which(program) is not None

def exitWithError(error):
    print(error, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit()

def call(cmd):
    cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, encoding=__encoding_name__)
    cmdResult = cmd.communicate()
    return (cmd.returncode, cmdResult[0], cmdResult[1])

def getKeytoolCommand(withxxd = False):
    keytoolName = "keytool"
    if not cmdExist(keytoolName):
        exitWithError("Error: keytool command not found. Be sure the JDK is installed and available in the PATH")

    if withxxd:
        return keytoolName + " " + "-alias " + args.alias + " -exportcert -keystore " + args.keystore + " -storepass " + args.keypass + " | " + getxxdName() + " -p"
    else:
        return keytoolName + " " + "-alias " + args.alias + " -exportcert -keystore " + args.keystore + " -storepass " + args.keypass

def getxxdName():
    xxdName = "xxd"
    if isWindows():
        xxdName = "xxd_w"
    if not cmdExist(xxdName):
        exitWithError("Error: " + xxdName + " not found. If you are on Windows, the program xxd_w.exe must be placed in the current folder")
    return xxdName

def getSignature():
    keytoolCommand = getKeytoolCommand()
    returncode, out, err = call(keytoolCommand)
    if returncode != 0:
        print(out)
        print(err)
        exitWithError("keytool command failed. Please check the alias and the password are correct")
    return out

def getHexSignature():
    keytoolWithxxd = getKeytoolCommand(True)
    returncode, out, err = call(keytoolWithxxd)
    if returncode != 0:
        print(out)
        print(err)
        exitWithError("keytool | xxd command failed")
    return out

def removeWhitespaces(value):
    return "".join(value.split())

def appendApplicationId(value):
    return args.appid + " " + value

def computeSha256(value):
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(value.encode(__encoding_name__))
    return m.digest()

def formatSignature(signature):
    signatureNoSpaces = removeWhitespaces(signature)
    return appendApplicationId(signatureNoSpaces)

# Call getSignature() to check if the alias and password provided are correct: if not correct the program exits with error
signature = getSignature()
hexSignature = getHexSignature()

formattedSignature = formatSignature(hexSignature)
sha256 = computeSha256(formattedSignature)
base64 = base64.b64encode(sha256)

# The hash to use for the SMS is the first 11 chars
print(base64.decode(__encoding_name__)[0:11])
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is a way to download deployment_cert.der from google play console? I have never did it and can't find Google directions how to do that.

Comment: 1) Open the Play Console. 2) Select an app. 3) On the left menu, select Release > Setup > App signing. Also you can read [app signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en)

Comment: What should I answer on a question running your step 2 `Trust this certificate? [no]:` ?

Comment: Answer is: `yes`

Comment: A result of your step 4 is `Error: xxd_w not found. If you are on Windows, the program xxd_w.exe must be placed in the current folder`. Did you try your pythoon script on Windows machine?

Comment: No, only on macOS and Linux.

Comment: Try with terminal. keytool -exportcert -alias PlayDeploymentCert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

Comment: `"xxd" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.` That means "xxd not found".

Comment: Please, mark your answer as useless for Windows machines to avoid of wasting time on it.

Comment: The main point is mentioned in the answer of **iam.vikas**: "**Right click and choose "Git Bash Here***. You have to run `keytool -exportcert -alias PlayDeploymentCert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp cat | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11` in **Git Bash**, not a Windows CMD!!!

Comment: thanks bro it works for me.. very legit answer for mac user.. approved :+1:

Answer (score 2):

***Where can I find my "public key certificate", and where am I supposed to run this command?***

When you run an android app, the apk needs to be signed by an certificate before it is installed in the device. If you're running your app in debug mode, by default, the apk is signed by an certificate that is inside the keystore at this location `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore` (this can be changed if you want). If you generate a release apk, you must specify your Keystore location. [More info here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

***What is SHA-256 and what does it mean to compute it?***

As Chintam Anand [explained on Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-SHA-256-SHA2-and-why-is-it-used/answer/Chintam-Anand).

> SHA is a component of an SSL certificate used to ensure that data has
>   not been modified.SHA accomplishes this by computing a cryptographic
>   function and any change to a given piece of data will result in a
>   different hash value. As a result, differing hash values are key to
>   determining if data has been altered.

One of the steps in the mentioned guide shows a complete command that does each of the steps for you. Including computing the sha-256 and base encoding its value. Done when you run the `sha256sum` and `base64` commands.

***Can't understand, what am I supposed to do here?***

You just need to replace `MyAndroidKey` and `MyProductionKeys.keystore` with your keystore alias and keystore location.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

I recently wrote a blog post about this relating some of the common problems and with a full working example. [check it out for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode).

Answer (score 2):

For **mac** users please note the command to generate the hash ::

```
keytool -exportcert -alias “youralias” -keystore /Path/to/your/app/keys/your.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d “[:space:]” | echo -n your.package.name `cat` | shasum -a 256 | tr -d “[:space:]-” | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c 1–11
```

please change the `youralias`, `/Path/to/your/app/keys/your.keystore` and `your.package.name` to make the script work

Comment: Mac users - check this script. https://github.com/kesha-antonov/android-sms-verification-hash
It works 100%!

Comment: I am getting this error any possible solution `-bash: sha256sum: command not found` and `-bash: echo: write error: Broken pipe`

Answer (score 1):

Note: The following solution is only for windows user (It may or may not work in other OS)

I was facing "xxd not recognized as an internal or external command" in windows. After solving this issue, I started facing "tr: write error" issue in windows. I spent a whole day but couldn't find a proper solution.

Finally, the solution which worked for me is mentioned below:

1. Install git if you don't have it already. (because xxd, tr is already present inside git). In my case it was already installed.
2. Add Java bin directory path inside the Environment Variable called "Path". In my case, the path looks like - "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin".
3. Now, go to the folder where you have already downloaded your App's Signed Certificate (deployment_cert.der). Right click and choose "Git Bash Here". It will open git command line with the folder path in which you have your .der file.

Note: You can also open git from anywhere but in this case, you need to specify the absolute path of App Signing Certificate in the command mentioned in Step 4.

4. As mentioned in [Google original document](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string), We first have to import the certificate inside a temporary keystore with the following command (use git command line):

   ```
    keytool -importcert -file <APP_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE> -keystore <KEYSTORE_FILE> -alias <USER_DEFINED_ALIAS>
   ```

Here,

- APP_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE : Absolute path of your certificate (or just
  give the certificate name if you are already in the directory where
  you have your certificate)
- KEYSTORE_FILE : Any name with .keystore extension
- USER_DEFINED_ALIAS : Any name, make sure to remember it.

5. You will be asked to give a password - type your password. After giving a password it will ask you to trust the certificate, kindly type "yes" and hit enter.
6. As a final step, let's generate the hash string by using the alias, Keystore file mentioned above. We'll also have to specify the app package name in this step:

   ```
    keytool -exportcert -alias USER_DEFINED_ALIAS -keystore KEYSTORE_FILE | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n APP_PACKAGE_NAME `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
   ```

Here,

- USER_DEFINED_ALIAS : Please give the alias given in Step 4.
- KEYSTORE_FILE : Please give the key store file name as given in Step 4.
- APP_PACKAGE_NAME : Please enter the package name of your Andriod App.

7. You will be prompted to type the password again (which you have entered in step 4). Once you enter the password, the hash string will be displayed on the git command line. Hurray!!!

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account `PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES` deprecation in API 28 the **Teja**'s answer should be rewritten as:

```
public class AppSignatureHelper extends ContextWrapper {
    public static final String TAG = AppSignatureHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
    public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
    public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

    public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getAppSignatures();
    }

    /**
     * Get all the app signatures for the current package
     * @return
     */
    public List<String> getAppSignatures() {
        ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        try {// Get all package signatures for the current package
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                SigningInfo sig = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES).signingInfo;
                if (sig.hasMultipleSigners()) // Send all with apkContentsSigners
                    return getAppCodes(sig.getApkContentsSigners(), packageName);
                else 
                    return getAppCodes(sig.getSigningCertificateHistory(), packageName);
            } else {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
                return getAppCodes(signatures, packageName);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
        }
        return appCodes;
    }

    private static List<String> getAppCodes(Signature[] signatures, String packageName) {
        List<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();
        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null)
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            Log.v(TAG, "Hash " + hash);
        }
        return appCodes;
    }

    private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
        String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
        try {
            MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();
            hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);// truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
            String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);// encode into Base64
            base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
            return base64Hash;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### In case anyone is interested in Kotlin version of [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54052163/2115403) answer:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import java.util.Arrays

/*
  This is a helper class to generate your message hash to be included in your SMS message.
  Without the correct hash, your app won't receive the message callback. This only needs to be
  generated once per app and stored. Then you can remove this helper class from your code.
*/
@Suppress("PrivatePropertyName")
class SignHelper(context: Context) : ContextWrapper(context) {
    private val TAG = SignHelper::class.java.simpleName
    private val HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256"
    private val NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9
    private val NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11

    val signatures = ArrayList<String>()

    init {
        try {
            for (signature in packageManager.getPackageInfo(
                packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures) {
                val hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString())
                if (hash != null) signatures.add(String.format("%s", hash)) }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e)
        }
    }

    private fun hash(packageName: String, signature: String): String? = try {
        MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE).run {
            update("$packageName $signature".toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            Base64.encodeToString(Arrays.copyOfRange(digest(), 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES),
                Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.NO_WRAP).substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR).also {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, it)) } }
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) { Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm", e); null }
}
```

Then you can call the code below in your main Activity.

```
println(SignHelper(this).signatures.first())
```

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically obtain app hash from the device.
**Compatible with Android API 32**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.util.Base64
import android.util.Log
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.security.MessageDigest
import java.util.*

fun hash(context: Context) {
    for (signature in getSignatures(context)) {
        hash(context.packageName, signature.toCharsString())
    }
}

private fun getSignatures(context: Context) = context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(
    context.packageName,
    PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES
).signingInfo?.run {
    if (hasMultipleSigners()) apkContentsSigners else signingCertificateHistory
} ?: arrayOf()


private fun hash(packageName: String, signature: String) =
    MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").run {
        update("$packageName $signature".toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        Base64.encodeToString(
            Arrays.copyOfRange(digest(), 0, 9),
            Base64.NO_PADDING or Base64.NO_WRAP
        ).substring(0, 11).also {
            Log.d("hash", String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, it))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For mac I wrote ruby script exactly for this:

https://github.com/kesha-antonov/android-sms-verification-hash

Just clone repo and run script

```
$ ruby get_sms_verification_hash.rb --package com.yourcompany.appname --keystore ../AppName/android/app/release-key.keystore --alias release-key --storepass MyPass123

Your hash for verification sms: SQQpXpxMN75
```

Answer (score 0):

How I worked this out was to use the helper classes which have been added as answers above, navigate to -> Build -> Select build variant -> select the Release build variant (depends and varies based on how your project is) and then after choosing the Release, you can call the helper function to get the hashcode for the release build and use the same in the sms with otp being sent to the application

Answer (score 0):

I know it is too late, but this is the command that worked for me, on MAC's terminal.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias my_alias -keystore path_to_my_keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n my_app_package_name `cat` | shasum -a 256 | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

**Note:**

1. Change *my_alias* in the above to the alias of your keystore
2. Change *path_to_my_keystore* in the above to the exact path of your keystore
3. Change *my_app_package_name* in the above to your app's package name

May it help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a simple & straightforward answer when I had this problem on **Windows**. So I'm posting this for the sake of others.

First open git bash (this is a command line which comes with git when you install it).

Then run the following commands (replacing your own keystore information):

```
# Replace these:
package=com.example.your_app_package
keystore="location/of/your/keystore_file"
keystorepass=android
alias=androiddebugkey
# Run this (keytool program is located in $JAVA_HOME/bin):
keytool -exportcert -alias $alias -keystore $keystore -storepass $keystorepass | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n $package `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to send the **AppSignatureHelper** key in you SMS template also. this way android will auto read the SMS.