# SMS Retriever API always results in timeout, inspite of right message format

Tags: android

Here is my MySMSBroadcastReceiver

```
package com.example.gofresh;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                Toast.makeText(context,"OTP: "+message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Tag","OTP: " +message);
                break;
            case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                Toast.makeText(context,"TIMEOUT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Tag","FAIL");
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<receiver
            android:name=".MySMSBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my first layout, there is a Name and Phone number Text Field, to be entered manually by the user. Below this is a button, titled "Let's go!". 
The second layout contains a pinView for the OTP. Below is my onClick Method which is called when the button is being clicked

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        if (next.getText().equals("Let's go!")) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            username = userName.getText().toString();
            phoneNumber = "+91" + userPhone.getText().toString();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
                if (phoneNumber.length() == 13) {
                    next.setText("Verify");

                    first.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    topText.setText("I still don't trust you.\nTell me something that only the two of us know.");

                    SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this );

                    Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();

                    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.i("TAG","Started Operation Successfully");
                        }
                    });

                    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.i("TAG","Operation Failed");
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Invalid Number Entered.\nNumber must be of 10 digits", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Please enter the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (next.getText().equals("Verify")) {


            String OTP_Entered = pinView.getText().toString();
            if(OTP_Entered.equals(OTP_Received)){
                pinView.setLineColor(Color.GREEN);
                textU.setText("OTP Verified");
                textU.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                goToHomeScreen();
            }else{
                pinView.setLineColor(Color.RED);
                textU.setText("Incorrect OTP");
                textU.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }


    }
```

Output Log:

```
2019-06-10 16:10:46.830 12864-12864/com.example.gofresh I/TAG: Started Operation Successfully
2019-06-10 16:18:14.372 12864-12864/com.example.gofresh I/Tag: FAIL
2019-06-10 16:18:14.395 12864-12864/com.example.gofresh I/Tag: FAIL
```

My Message Format:

```
<#> Your Example Code is: 123456 FA+9qCX9VSu
```

Comment: I see....  why are you using sample Hash from Document ? You need to create your hash .. Follow https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @zeroDivider please see the solution, do upvote if this helps :)

Comment: I guessed it was problem in my app, but I haven't find the time to work on it yet :( but many thanks for writing the answer :) gj&gl

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is really simple. Each application has it's own unique Hash.
How this hash is generated can be found over here [Android - SMS Retriever API - Computing app's hash string problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849023/android-sms-retriever-api-computing-apps-hash-string-problem)

Hope this helps

Comment: I did it, still the issue