# Generating hash string for google sms retriever api - 'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, api, hash, keytool, one-time-password

After the google's new policy regarding SMS and Call log permissions, I am trying to implement SMS retriever API for my android application.
The tutorial seems easy but I found a problem while creating/generating hash for the same.

**When I type**

```
keytool -alias MyAndroidKey -exportcert -keystore MyProduction.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]"
```

OR

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

**It says:**

```
'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

'tr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

There are no clarification available on https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string page

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Finally I managed to get hash key for using SMS retriever API - Android.

**Steps I followed.**

1. I was using Git so it was installed on my machine. Head over to C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin and I see that it has xxd.exe and tr.exe which was my requirement.
2. So I added the environment variable to Path > New > C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
3. Restart the cmd with administrator privileges. xxd and tr command started working.

Hope this will help others as google has stopped CALL_LOG, READ_SMS permission.

**Cheers.**

**---------------------UPDATE-----------------------**

**I found an another good answer here.**

Please follow the link it gives a **step by step tut for creating the hash key**.

I followed this because **after publishing app to play store the generated hash key doesn't work any more**.

[How to generate 11 char hash key for Sms Retriever with Google App signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing)

Hope it will help someone!

Comment: when i try to generate my hash following error occurs
tr: write error: Illegal seek

Comment: @Mohsin Make sure you are starting cmd with administrator privileges

Comment: I'm using git and my app is not in google play yet. I just create ocal jks key. But command can not find xxd

Comment: xxd.exe and tr.exe should be there right in C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin for Windows or any equivalent directory if you are using mac or linux

Answer (score 6):

[UPDATED for windows]

```
# xxd
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xxd
# tr
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr
# base64
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\base64
```

The whole commands become

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore certificate.jks | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xxd" -p |"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr" -d "[:space:]" | echo -n PACKAGE_NAME `cat` | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sha256sum" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\tr" -d "[:space:]-" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\xxd" -r -p | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\base64" | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\cut" -c1-11
```

Comment: That's true assuming that the user has all these commands installed under these paths. Worth trying, anyway.

Comment: Yaa. I should have mentioned that if somebody does not know the path of these then he/she can search his drives (probably C) to find its .exe file. The path of .exe file is the thing we are putting it there.

Answer (score 2):

In Window, if you are using SourceTree you will search with `xxd.exe` keyword or find it with `C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\usr\bin` path.

Example: `keytool -alias MyKey -exportcert -keystore MyKey.keystore | C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\usr\bin\xxd -p | C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\usr\bin\tr -d "[:space:]"`

You can download [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bsmh0ubg6pa51sr/xxd_tr.rar/file)

Comment: Hi thanks, but I could not find Atlassian directory in C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\

Comment: Change the `your_user_name` to your username which you use to login the PC

Comment: You can download [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/bsmh0ubg6pa51sr/xxd_tr.rar/file)

Comment: I know that :p, Okay so I have installed Source tree, I can see Atlassian directory, but there is no git_local directory

Comment: There is hg_local directory

Comment: I give you a link to download it. Check my answer or my previous comment. Hope it helps

Comment: Done. @john Thanks for the help.