# SMS retriever api wont read OTP from SMS automatically in release build

Tags: android, hash, sms, one-time-password

I generated Hash from AppSignatureHelper class which works for debug build, same didn't work for release build, so I generated a hash using keystore and alias using command https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string and updated to SMS text, this too didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate 11 char hash key for Sms Retriever with Google App signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this solved my problem [How to generate 11 char hash key for Sms Retriever with Google App signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing?noredirect=1&lq=1#)

The solution mentioned by [@farhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961874/farhan-farooqui) in his question helped

Answer (score 4):

First publish app on play store then do these steps :

1. Go to Release management in developer console.
2. Click on App signing.

I have added an example you can check in below SS.

[image]

**EDIT 1:-**

Steps for **Release** **Hashkey**:

- Download Openssl (Download from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip&can=2&q=)), I have downloaded for **64 bit** OS, you can find more [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list)
- Extract downloaded zip file to C:\ drive only
- Open command prompt
- `keytool -exportcert -alias **myaliasname** -keystore **"C:\Users\hiren.patel\Desktop\mykeystore.jks"** | "C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64`

Kindly change **Alias Name** and **Keystore with it's path** as your requirement.

#### Note:

**Please put your details where I have marked between ** **.**

Terminal would **ask** for **Password** of Keystore. You have to **provide password** for the same **Keystore**.

So finally you would get the **Release Hashkey**.

**Done**

**EDIT 2:**

Use this command in linux :

```
echo 33:4E:48:84:19:50:3A:1F:63:A6:0F:F6:A1:C2:31:E5:01:38:55:2E | xxd -r -p | openssl base64
```

if you don't have linux OS then you can do this online : 
using this link :

https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

**Note : USE API SIGNING KEY FROM DEVELOPER CONSOLE.**
[image]

**Edit 3:**

Try generating hash without alias for Google APK Sign Enabled

i.e

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

**NOTE : SHA-256 certificate fingerprint, take this from developer console**

Comment: app is published,.I need 11 character hash

Comment: @wasim check EDIT 2 also

Comment: this will not give 11 digit character which is required to be added to SMS text right?
let me get first 11 character of encoded hash and try

Comment: i tried with first 11 characters of the hash obtained by generating using online compiler, it didn't help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186787/discussion-between-wasim-and-abhinav-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found solution for SMS retriever api wont read OTP from SMS automatically in release build using below script.

download this file
https://github.com/michalbrz/sms-retriever-hash-generator/blob/master/google_play_sign.rb

Change this code in script

--package **NAME**               Your app package, e.g com.test.app

--google-play-key **KEY_PATH**   Google Play public key (in DER format) used to sign release app

--keystore **KEYSTORE_PATH**     Path to keystore (.jks file)

--keystore-password **PASSWORD** Password to the keystore - required only when option "--keystore" is specified

--key-alias **KEY_ALIAS**        Alias of key in the keystore - required only when option "--keystore" is specified

Then run below command

ruby google_play_sign.rb --package com.your.app --google-play-key deployment_cert.der