# SMS Retriver API not working on Playstore Derived Build, But working in uploaded original build, Why?

Tags: android, react-native, sms-retriever-api

I worked on SMS retriever API (React Native Application Version = 0.59.5) and it worked successfully for my earlier app versions on debug mode, release mode and Play store also using package [react-native-sms-retriever V-1.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever). But last time, I updated build and SMS retriver API is stopped auto fetch message functionality. I tried to generate Hash key once again and they were same as in earlier builds. I used both [commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing) and also [AppSignatreHelper](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) to generate hash key and both are same in the release mode and working fine. But when I updated APK in google play console it is not working.
Can anyone help with this issue.

Comment: add more details about your question like error messages, code segments which you tried.

Comment: I implemented [native-sms-retriever V-1.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sms-retriever/v/1.0.3) in my react-native package 3 months ago.
I generated hash key using both command line and Appsignaturehelper class.
Both produced same hash key.
First when uploaded app to the playstore it is working fine. After that no changes made in code till the last updation of App in playstore. On 28th Feb I updated our app in playstore and It stopped autofetch OTP in the Playstore build. But the build generated is working fine, once it goes to the playstore it is stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a different hash key for the release version but use the command way not  AppSignatreHelper

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify

Comment: Yes, I have generated hash key for the release and I have updated builds 2 times in playstore after that and working fine in those two builds. But last time when updated the app and pushed to play store, the SMS retriever stopped working.
So Even I checked if any hash key changes has happened or not using commands and AppSignatreHelper but in both ways I obtained the same hash key as before for the last builds.

Comment: Have you used the app signing certificate file (deployment_cert.der)  from  Google Play console?

Comment: Yes. I used it.