# HASH string key on published APK in SMS Retriever API

Tags: java, android, google-api, sms-retriever-api

A lot of these questions were asked. but none worked for me.

**Question:**

I was able to get the correct key using [AppSignatureHelper.java](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java) in debug mode and all working as expected. And I've published my app on play store and used the same class on signed apk to retrieve HASH key but it's not working. I tried all other ways mentioned in a lot previous questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829661/6465824). and below code using keystore:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias PlayDeploymentCert -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

None of them working in the published app. SMS simply not reading!! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your app package name ?

Comment: You need to mention it while generating the hash string. Replace com.example.myapp with your app package name and also make sure you are using the right keystore file name

Comment: above is a sample. I tried with correct keystore data and package

Comment: Are you sure that you downloaded App signing certificate named deployment_cert.der from google play store if your app signed by google play ?

Comment: yes. and I've got 11 digit HASH key but it's not working

Comment: Seems intresting ...Let me know if you ressolve the error

Answer (score 1):

You should get the hash key from the keystore file not from AppSignatureHelper class ...

Google in its documentation mentioned it officially **"If you use the helper class, be sure to remove it from your app after you get the hash string"**

So generate the hash key from the keystore file ...

Check this on how to generate the Hash String : [Computing your app hash string](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#computing_your_apps_hash_string)

> Note : If you use app signing by Google Play, download your app
>   signing certificate (deployment_cert.der) from the App signing section
>   of the Google Play console.
>
> Then, import the app signing certificate into a temporary key store

Comment: HI, I've already tried this. but SMS not reading with this key. I've updated my question

Comment: the debug key is working fine. so I don't think is there any issue with code. I've followed official docs.