# Auto-detecting verification code of firebase auth is not working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

I am working on an flutter app that requires to verify users mobile number by sending an OTP. I am using Firebase phone authentication for this purpose. Everything working fine till I upload the app to play store. After uploading the app to the play store the SMS auto retrieve feature is no longer working.(the SMS doesn't contain the **11 digit** hash key after uploading to play store).

*below requirements are fulfilled*

- adding the sha-1 and sha-256 key from google play app-signing in play console
- enable device check API in cloud console
- enable mobile authentication in Firebase console

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am searching for this issue from last 2 day without any result.

Comment: till now what i found is the issue is for large name in the app in play store that is exceeding the verification sms size of 64kb make it eliminate the app hash from the end of the message

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51365778/how-to-generate-11-char-hash-key-for-sms-retriever-with-google-app-signing

Answer (score 0):

Try using these versions #firebase_core: "^0.7.0" and #firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"

Answer (score 0):

(editing to clarify per suggestion)
If your app has not yet been reviewed in the Play Store, the SMS message will include the full package name (instead of your app name) with the additional string of "(unreviewed)". Depending on the length of your package name, this can effect the SMS message size and possibly truncate it to not include the 11 char hash at the end of the SMS, which is required for auto-complete to function.

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: I have published my app for internal testing and it has been reviewed but in the OTP message, I'm still getting <project-id>.firebaseapp.com and it's not being updated from playstore. Also how can I include 11 char hash? Any help will be greatly appreciated, I'm trying to solve this issue for days now.